# Showing a function is infinitely many times differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by

$f(x)=exp(-\frac{a^2}{a^2-x^2})$ when $|x|<a$ and $f(x)=0$ other wise. Show that $f$ is infinitely many times differentiable.

Now I know that the function $g(x)=exp(-x^{-2})$ when $x<0$ and $g(x)=0$ other wise is infinitely many times differentiable. But how  use $g$ to show that $f$ is diffrentiable?

Answer (score 1):

There is no information on the range of $a$ and it is important in the problem. Anyway, I will write an outline if $a\in \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}$.

The function $f$ is defined as \begin{align*} f: X\subseteq \mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\\ x&\longmapsto \begin{cases} e^{-\frac{a^{2}}{a^{2}-x^{2}}}, \quad x\in \left]-a,a\right[,\\ 0, \quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}  \end{align*}

1. For all $x\in \left] -a,a\right[$ we have that $f$ is the composition of functions infinitely many times differentiable.  Hence $f$ is infinitely many times differentiable over $]-a,a[$.
2. Now we need to study the differentiabilty in the "otherwise" for $f$. On the intervals $]-\infty, -a[$ and $[a,+\infty[$ there is not problem by definition of $f$. However we need to see in the neighbourhood at $x=-a$ and $x=a$ which could give problems in the differentiable nature of the function $f$.
   2.1. In $x=-a$ we need to study by definition the derivative of $f$. In this part we need to see $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to -a; x\in X\setminus \{-a\}}\frac{f(x)-f(-a)}{x-(-a)}$ that if it exists it is by definition $f'(-a)$. Then if $f'(-a)=0$ you can use induction mathematical on $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and see if $f^{(n)}(-a)=0$. Similar reasoning with $x=a$.
3. If everything works, then you can conclude that $f$ is infinitely many times differentiable over its entire domain, and the result follows.